# Count number of specific characters or strings in a txt file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

If I load a txt file into my flash movie using the following...

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();


myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var myArrayOfLines:Array = e.target.data.split("a")
    trace(myArrayOfLines);

}

myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("OoS/OoS-intro.txt"));
```

I get my text imported and it splits it every time the letter 'a' is found. That's fine.

How would I go about counting the number of times that 'a' or 'and' (for example) featured in the text?

Thanks for any help offered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, using `str.split('a')`, with the example input of `"a"`, you get a result of length 2. So, using `str.split` you could assume that the count of times that letter is featured in the test is the length of `str.split`'s result array - 1.

```
var res:Array = "a".split('a');
trace (res.length) // 2
trace (res) // , -- empty string on either side of the split
var count:int = res.length - 1 // 1

res = "aa".split('a');
trace (res.length) // 3
trace (res) // , , -- empty string times 3!
count = res.length - 1 // 2
```

It's not the best solution, but it does work. You could also use a `RegExp`, or a variety of other methods.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that :) I don't explicitly want split. I just need to count the number of times a character or word appears in the text (or is split how that would normally be done anyway?) Sorry if my original post was misleading. Also, how would I feed my .txt into that code (in place of "a")?

Comment: @3quid Exactly how you're already doing it. Load, in the listener do `res:array = e.target.data.split('a');` and then follow the rest of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// less objects created:
var s:String = "  sfd sfd aa sfd  sa asfd asfd  asfd  asdf  asdf aa";
trace( s.match(/a/g).length );

// more generically:
var txt:String = "a";
var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp(txt,"g"); 
trace(s.match(pattern).length);

// to see what is going on:
trace(s.split("a").length);
trace(s.split("a"));
trace(s.match(/a/g));
```

Replace 'a' with any text.